# Can you delay transactions so that you pay no fees?

Tags: transaction-fees

Online wallets, such as inputs.io, require you to pay a fee, but transactions occur instantly. Is there any way to not pay fees (probably by delaying payments)?

Comment: It entirely depends on whether the wallet provider allows it. inputs.io doesn't seem to - there is no API for it anyway.

Comment: Keep in mind that even if someone accepts a transaction as having occurred instantly, it still takes a while for it to be accepted into the block chain, and there isn't a [good or reliable] way to rush this.Once the transaction has gone through, it could still be reversed if there is a fork in the block-chain, but the more confirmations a transaction has, the less likely this is to happen. Also, inputs.io is likely paying a fee, but by bundling many payments into one transaction, they fee is relatively small compared to each individual payment so they just pay it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Transaction fees](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees) will always be expected by the network unless your order meets these conditions

- It is smaller than 10,000 bytes.
- All outputs are 0.01 BTC or larger
- Its priority is large enough (meaning it has been on hold for a very long time)

you can also mine your own transactions, but as a general rule if your expecting someone to process your order for you, then they expect something in return, even if that something is only 0.0001 BTC.